# Get Information about the used Libraries of application

Tags: java, classpath

Is there a chance to get an information about libraries used in my java application?

Example: If I deploy my application on glassfish, the glassfish has it's own libraries and my application has own. If I use a newer version of a lib as the glassfish has, I want to test/log that my lib is used.

Comment: Are you using Maven or some other tool to build your code and manage dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The reflection API lets you find some information about classes loaded into the application. For example assuming the library that includes `SomeClass` is loaded from a .jar file that includes version information you can use:

```
Package libPackage = SomeClass.class.getPackage();
String libVersion = libPackage.getSpecificationVersion();
```

If the .jar file does not include version information you can still find out its name with:

```
URL classLocation = SomeClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```